# Mysterious "ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8" inside scope in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I've been struggling with this for quite a while and I can't understand the issue. This only happens with a value loaded from the database.

I'm using Rails 4.0.13 and Ruby 2.0.0 by the way, using PostgreSQL

I have the following code:

```
class Term < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Search < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :filter, ->(params) {
     query = []
     unless params[:term].blank?
       for term in Array(params[:term]) do
         query << "term = '#{term.gsub('"', '""')}'"
       end
     end

     where(query.join(' or '))
  }
end
```

Then, there's a term called "100%Carbs". If I try to filter by it like this, I get the following error:

```
term = Term.find 1
Search.filter(term: term.term)

ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
from /home/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb:93:in `=~'
from /home/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb:93:in `!~'
from /home/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb:93:in `blank?'
from /home/app/releases/20160603154616/app/models/search.rb:4:in `block in <class:Search>'
```

But if I write the term on my own, I get a different error:

```
Search.filter(term: "100%Carbs")

PG::CharacterNotInRepertoire: ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xca 0x72
: SELECT "search".* FROM "search"  WHERE ((term_store->'term' = '100�rbs'))
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::CharacterNotInRepertoire: ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xca 0x72
: SELECT "search".* FROM "search"  WHERE ((term_store->'term' = '100�rbs'))
```

I've tried a number of combinations of the methods encode and force_encoding, and I always get this error.

The only real difference I noticed between the two attempts is that they have different encoding when they go in the method:

```
2.0.0 :004 > "100%Carbs".encoding
 => #<Encoding:ISO-8859-1> 
2.0.0 :005 > term.term.encoding
 => #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

I really don't understand what's triggering this error, or why the percent character seems to be treated as something else instead of just a character. I've tried to escape it as well, with no success.

I'm really lost here and would appreciate any and all help. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure there's no HTTP involved anywhere? Smells like something is URI-decoding `%CA` somewhere and producing invalid UTF-8. Also, your quoting approach looks a bit off, you should be using ActiveRecord or database connection methods for that. And what's going on with the `<<` in your class definitions? Don't you mean `<`?

Comment: Apart from the security concerns (constructing queries with string interpolation/concatenation is *very* dangerous), how is this query supposed to work? Suppose `params[:term]` is `["foo", "bar"]`. This scope will construct a query like `where("term = 'foo' and term = 'bar'")`, which will never return any results (because a field cannot be equal to two different values at once). The only way this scope will return any results is if `params[:term]` has only one item, or all of its items are the same.

Comment: I'm sure there's no HTTP involved. The problem definitely lies with the %CA though. If I add a space after the %, I don't get the error when I write the string, but still get it from the DB. The << in the class definitions was my mistake when adding the code here.

Comment: Hi Jordan, that was my mistake on simplying the code to add here as well. It should be "or". I've edited the original question.

Comment: I've managed to work around this issue by adding a gsub('%', '%25') to the param. Still no idea what's going on.

Comment: Open the JavaScript console in your browser and say `decodeURIComponent('%25')`. Then go and figure out why there is URI decoding going on.

Comment: What does this `search` table look like and why is a query like `where term = 'x'` being converted to `where ((term_store->'term' = 'x'))`?

Comment: dealing with encodings is very confusing. Not an answer to your question, but this is my favorite article on the concepts involved. http://kunststube.net/encoding/  I think you need to understand the concepts to have any hope of solving it. Going past that, you need to know/understand about how ruby handles encodings, how postgres handles encodings, and what encoding your postgres db is set to. It is also disturbing to me that your string literal in console claims to have encoding `ISO-8859-1`, this would normaly be utf and that's gonna make things even more confusing. are you on windows?

Comment: mu, I've really simplified the code before posting it here, since this is a huge project. We have the value saved inside an hstore, but same thing happens if I query a character varying field, and I copied the error from my hstore attempt. Also, thank you for helping me get to the URI decoding problem... now to figure out what exactly is happening to cause it.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, jrochkind. I'll be sure to read up on that. And no, I was running the console on our Ubuntu server when I got that encoding. This is all really weird since we've never had encoding problems before.